# Rails associations logical vs code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building my first application with Ruby on Rails (version 5.2.4.2 with ruby 2.6.3) and am having an issue with one of the associations. In my model there are applications in which you supply a single company that you are applying to. Logically I would like to be able to get an application and say `application.company = Company.find_by(...)`.

To make this work, I have

```
# app/models/Application.rb
class Application < ApplicationRecord
  has_one: company
end

# app/models/Company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
end

# database migration
Class AddCompanyToApplication
  def change
    add_reference :companies, :application, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Doing this allows me to use the desired syntax but has one issue. When I create a second application for the same company, the row in the companies table is changed that removes the company from the first application.

The list of companies is predetermined and I just want to refer to a company from within the application. Is there a way to be able to use the assignment syntax while having the foreign key placed in application rather than companies? From a database perspective I feel like application should hold the foreign key, but this breaks the assignment syntax. It seems like Ruby wants me to make Company have has_many :applications, but this breaks the semantics of what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a way to change the foreign key placement or should I forgo the assignment syntax and stick to SQL and assigning directly to id's?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have a 1 to 1 relationship. An application `has_one :company` and a company `belongs_to :application`. That's why when you try to create a second application for the same company, the `application_id` in the companies table gets overridden. If you change your company association to `has_many :applications`, you should be able to add more than one application to a company. Then you can call `application.company` to return the application's current company or `application.company = ...` to assign a company to the current application.

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applications
end
```

To make this work, you have to create a new migration:

```
Class AddCompanyIdToApplication
  def change
    add_reference :application, :company, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Before you do that, you have to rollback your existing AddCompanyToApplication migration (which is named wrong, by the way, because you're not adding the company to the application, you're adding the application to the company) and delete the AddCompanyToApplication migration.

Read more about [associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Read more about [add_reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference)